# Least Squares: Derivation of Normal Equations with Chain Rule

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, least-squares

I'm new to Stackexchange so please bear with me. I'm struggling
with the least squares formula. Now Wikipedia does show ways
to derive the "[normal equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Derivation_of_the_normal_equations)".

But I'd like to get the same result using the Chain Rule.
Which would be something like this (I don't know if it's possible for matrices,
since I haven't seen this approach anywhere yet):

$$(y - Xb)^2$$

and differentiating it with respect to $b$, which would be something like:

$$2(y - Xb) * (-X)$$

It seems though, that a transpose sign is missing somewhere, since
the formula should look as follows:

$$ \mathbf{-X}^{\rm T} \mathbf y+ (\mathbf X^{\rm T} \mathbf X ){\boldsymbol{b}}$$

Please help me to correct this or point out if I'm totally wrong.

Comment: Well for one thing you're missing a minus sign after the derivative with respect to $b$, from the internal derivative ($-X$).

Comment: $(y-Xb)^2$ doesn't make sense if $y$ is a vector. You should write $(y-Xb)^\top(y-Xb)$ as your objective function.

Answer (score 3):

To get the derivative of the formula $(y-{X}b)^T (y-Xb)$, we can use the **Chain Rule** as follows:

Let $f(b) = y-Xb, g(u) = u^Tu$ where $u = f(b)$. then,

$$
\eqalign{
\frac {\partial [(y-{X}b)^T (y-Xb)]} {\partial b} &= \frac {\partial g(u)} {\partial u} \times \frac {\partial f(b)} {\partial b}
}$$

Note that since $g(u)$ is in quadratic form($\partial X^TI_{n}X = 2X$), the derivative of $g(u)$ can be directly derived:

$$
\eqalign {
\frac {\partial g(u)} {\partial u} &= \frac {\partial u^Tu} {\partial u}   &= 2u^T \cr
}$$

$u^T$ is a $1 \times n$ row vector to keep compatible with $\partial f(b)$.

$$
\eqalign {
\frac {\partial f(b)} {\partial b}   &= \frac {\partial (y-Xb)} {\partial b} \cr
                                     &= - \frac {\partial Xb} {\partial b} \cr
                                     &= -X ~~~(Jacobian ~matrix)
}$$

So,

$$
\eqalign{
\frac {\partial [(y-{X}b)^T (y-Xb)]} {\partial b} &= \frac {\partial g(u)} {\partial u} \times \frac {\partial f(b)} {\partial b} \cr
&= 2u^T \times (-X) \cr
&= -2(y-Xb)^TX ~~~(1 \times n ~row ~vector)
}$$

Finally transpose the result vector and we can get the familiar column vector:

$$
\eqalign{
[-2(y-Xb)^TX]^T &= -2X^T(y-Xb) 
&= -2X^Ty + 2X^TXb
}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Instead of $m\!\times\!1$ and $n\!\times\!1$ vectors for $y$ and $b$, it might be easier to consider $m\!\times\!p$ and $n\!\times\!p$ matrices.

Then the quantity to minimize is $f = \|Y-X\!\cdot\!B\|^2_F = \|M\|^2_F$

Rewriting this to use the Frobenius product, $f = M:M$, makes taking the derivative easier.  Here it is step by step.
$$ \eqalign {
df &= 2M:dM \cr
   &= 2M:d(Y-X\!\cdot\!B) \cr
   &= 2M:(-X\!\cdot\!dB) \cr
   &= 2(Y-X\!\cdot\!B):(-X\!\cdot\!dB) \cr
   &= 2(X\!\cdot\!B-Y):X\!\cdot\!dB \cr
   &= 2X^T\!\cdot(X\!\cdot\!B-Y):dB \cr
}$$
So the derivative with respect to $B$ is 
$$ \eqalign {
\frac {\partial f} {\partial B}   &= 2X^T\!\cdot(X\!\cdot\!B-Y) \cr
}$$
Equating it to zero yields the normal equations.

The step you are questioning is how $X$ gets transposed.  In the last step of the derivation, we used
$$ \eqalign {
 A:X\cdot\!B &= X^T\!\cdot\!A:B \cr
}$$
to move $X$ to the other size of the Frobenius product. Since the Frobenius product is really just a trace operation, it's easy to prove that 
$$ \eqalign {
 A:X\cdot\!B &= \text{tr}(A\!\cdot(X\cdot\!B)^T) \cr
   &= \text{tr}(A\!\cdot\!B^T\!\cdot\!X^T) \cr
   &= \text{tr}(X^T\!\cdot\!A\!\cdot\!B^T) \cr
   &= X^T\!\cdot\!A:B \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks :D... and sry for the typos. I was really hasty when asking the question. I will try to formulate my questions better. Your answer though is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, if your calculation is correct. Usually you have to minimze the following term:

$(y-xb)' \times (y-xb)$

$=(y'-b'x') \times (y-xb)$

multipying out.´

$=y'y-y'xb-b'x'y+b'x'xb$

It is $y'xb=b'x'y$

Thus you can write $=y'y-2b'x'y+b'x'xb$

Differentiate and set the derivative equal to 0.

$-2x'y+2x'xb=0$

Now solve this equation for b.

Comment: Well yes. I've already seen this a few times. I was just curious if it is possible to use the chain rule and get a similar result. Does this mean the chain rule is not applicable for matrices anymore?

Comment: @Nimi The problem here is not derivation. You get problems with the dimensions of the matrices, if you are calculating $(y-Xb) \times (y-Xb)$. Both factors have the dimension $n\times 1$. Thus multiplying doesn´t work.