# Least Squares: Derivation of Normal Equations with Chain Rule (Revisited)

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, machine-learning, least-squares

My question pertains to someone else's [answered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904017/least-squares-derivation-of-normal-equations-with-chain-rule) that has made me curious.  The OP wanted to differentiate the following using the chain rule:
$$
J(\theta)=\frac12(X\theta-y)^T(X\theta - y)
$$
The accepted answer used the Frobenius product with $m\times p$ and $n\times p$ matrices.  However, I'm still a bit confused as to why the OP's original approach failed.  Specifically, if $\theta$ is an $n\times 1$ vector and $y$ is an $m\times 1$ vector, then:
$$
u(\theta)=X\theta-y\\~\\
J(\theta)=\frac12u^Tu\\~\\
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial J}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\\~\\
=\frac12(2u)(X)\\~\\
=(X\theta-y)(X)\\~\\
=X\theta X-yX\\~\\
\not=X^TX\theta-X^Ty\\
$$
I'm obviously missing something when $\theta$ and $y$ remain vectors.  Anyone see my mistake?  Thanks.

---

Edit 1:
There are many proofs online that are perfectly fine; I'd just like to know how to correctly apply the chain rule when $\theta$ and $y$ are vectors.

---

Edit 2:
Being new to vector calculus, I've broken the problem down into summations to shed some light on what's happening:
$$
u(\theta)=
\begin{bmatrix}
     x_{11} & x_{12} & \ldots & x_{1n}\\
     x_{21} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{2n}\\
     \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
     x_{m1} & x_{m2} & \ldots & x_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
     \theta_1\\
     \theta_2\\
     \vdots\\
     \theta_n
\end{bmatrix} -
\begin{bmatrix}
     y_1\\
     y_2\\
     \vdots\\
     y_m
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
     \theta_1x_{11} + \theta_2x_{12} + \ldots + \theta_nx_{1n} - y_1\\
     \theta_1x_{21} + \theta_2x_{22} + \ldots + \theta_nx_{2n} - y_2\\
     \vdots\\
     \theta_1x_{m1} + \theta_2x_{m2} + \ldots + \theta_nx_{mn} - y_m
\end{bmatrix}\\~\\
u_i=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\theta_jx_{ij}\right)-y_i\\~\\
J(\theta)=\frac12u^Tu=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^mu_i^2\\~\\
=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^m\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\theta_jx_{ij}\right)-y_i\right]^2\\
$$
If we focus on only one partial derivative:
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta_1}=\frac12(2)\sum_{i=1}^m\left[x_{i1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\theta_jx_{ij}\right)-y_i\right]\\~\\
=\sum_{i=1}^m\left[x_{i1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\theta_jx_{ij}\right)-y_i\right]\\
$$
This is equivalent to:
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta_1}=
\begin{bmatrix}x_{11} & x_{21} & \ldots & x_{m1}\end{bmatrix}
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
     x_{11} & x_{12} & \ldots & x_{1n}\\
     x_{21} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{2n}\\
     \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
     x_{m1} & x_{m2} & \ldots & x_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
     \theta_1\\
     \theta_2\\
     \vdots\\
     \theta_n
\end{bmatrix} -
\begin{bmatrix}
     y_1\\
     y_2\\
     \vdots\\
     y_m
\end{bmatrix}\right)\\~\\~\\
=x_1^T(X\theta - y)
$$
And similarly, for all the partial derivatives:
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta}=X^T(X\theta - y)\\~\\
=X^TX\theta-X^Ty\\
$$
The interesting part is that when I perform the differentiation this way, the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}$ term correctly ends up on the left, and is transposed.  However, when I tried to use the chain rule directly, it incorrectly ends up on the right, not transposed:
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta}=X^T(X\theta - y)\\~\\
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta}\not=(X\theta-y)X\\
$$
Does anyone see where I am going wrong with the chain rule?  Any insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that what you are calling $\frac{\partial J}{\partial u}$ is equal to $u^T$, not $u$.

---

With that correction, here's how the calculation goes. Let $g(u) = \frac12 u^T u = \frac12 \| u \|^2$ and let $h(\theta) = X \theta - y$.
Note that $g'(u) = u^T$ and $h'(\theta) = X$.
The function $J$ is the composition of $g$ and $h$:
$$
J(\theta) = g(h(\theta)).
$$
By the chain rule,
\begin{align}
J'(\theta) &= g'(h(\theta)) h'(\theta) \\
&= (X \theta - y)^T X.
\end{align}
The gradient of $J$ is
$$
\nabla J(\theta) = J'(\theta)^T = X^T (X \theta - y).
$$

---

**Background knowledge:** If $F: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is differentiable at a point $x \in \mathbb R^n$, then $F'(x)$ is an $m \times n$ matrix which satisfies
$$
F(x + \Delta x) \approx F(x) + F'(x) \Delta x.
$$
The approximation is good when $\Delta x \in \mathbb R^n$ is small. This local linear approximation is the key idea of calculus.

If $F:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, then $F'(x)$ is a $1 \times n$ matrix (a row vector). The gradient of $F$ at $x$ is the column vector
$$
\nabla F(x) = F'(x)^T.
$$

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks.  I'd like to learn more; can you recommend a good book on the topic?

Comment: @SethTravis I'm not sure what book to recommended, but if you look through my stackexchange history I post about related topics sometimes.